# how do I pass pass parameters to redis BGSAVE command?

Tags: redis, synchronization, backup

I would like to run bgsave periodically, to sync data to the disk, I tried `BGSAVE 60 1000` to sync every 60 seconds or 1000 keys added but it does seem to work

Answer (score 1):

There's no such parameters for BGSAVE.

An approximate solution is to use the SAVE config. Config it in redis.conf or use the `config set` command:

```
config set save "60 1000"
```

However, this config means *after 60 seconds if at least 1000 changes was performed*. It's not exactly what's you need: *sync every 60 seconds or 1000 keys*.